# Wondering meaning in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

We walked all over paris for 5 hours wondering and tasting food .
I’d like to know the meaning of wondering in this sentence.

Comment: It's probably a typo - wandering.

Comment: Source please. Ideally with link.  Why is the dictionary definition not acceptable, the present participle of the verb "to wonder".

Comment: No link ,it’s a sentence that i’ve just read on FB .

Comment: I think asking about what looks like a "one-off" highly-questionable usage (almost certainly from a non-native speaker anyway) is essentially a form of Off-Topic proofreading (we can't really say what it "means" - sowe can only guess at *how it **should** have been expressed*).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a mistake, and should be wandering.

However, if it's really supposed to be wondering, it's an akward way to say that they were feeling awe and amazement.

> We walked all over paris for 5 hours wondering at the magnificent sights and tasting food